# Loop a 2D array vertically and choose one from each line

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops

How to loop a 2D array, such as

1  2  3  4

5  6  7  8

9 10 11 12

choose one from each line everytime, left first. The expected order for the example is:

1. 1 5 9
2. 2 5 9
3. 1 6 9
4. 1 5 10
5. 2 6 9
6. 2 5 10
7. 1 6 10
8. 2 6 10
   ....

Thanks.

Comment: Show your effort.

Comment: @vivek_23 what i can tell is I have thought for hours but noting came up.

Answer (score 0):

you can try two for loops

```
$a[$row][$column];
for($i=0; $i <$row; i++) {
   for($j=0; $j<$column;$j++){
    echo $a[$j][$i];
}
}
```

you can indent after 1 loop